# Block all personal sites in Sharepoint (Microsoft cannot help)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Is there a way to lock all personal sites.

I found a script to block one site

```
$siteUrl = "https://xxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/adelev_xxx_onmicrosoft_com"
$site = Get-SPOSite $siteUrl -Detailed
Set-SPOSite $site -LockState NoAccess
```

It works, but I have hundreds of sites to block. First I would need to list all sites and then one by one block them.
Hello,

Is there a way to automate it and BLOCK all sites?

I want to lock sites temporarily. This lock prevent users that has a personal site to use them (new ppl are blocked by MySite setting).

I contacted Microsoft directly and they provided me with some data - they told me that I should use ForEach, but I have no idea how to use it, and they won't help me any further cause it is against some policy.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up, what you need is to:

1. Get all personal sites
2. Run `Set-SPOSite` for each of them using any mechanism like `foreach`

Here's helpful article for 1: [Get a list of all user OneDrive URLs in your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/list-onedrive-urls). So, you need to run something like:

```
$allSites = Get-SPOSite -IncludePersonalSite $true -Limit all -Filter "Url -like '-my.sharepoint.com/personal/'" | Select -ExpandProperty Url
```

And for 2. you can use something similar to:

```
foreach ($site in $allSites) {
  Set-SPOSite -Identity $site -LockState NoAccess
}
```

Comment: Script worked currently, but I do not know how to check if status changed. I tried this:  Get-SPOSite -IncludePersonalSite $true it prints all sites, but how to print all sites with LockState status? Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.1). You might want to exclude `| Select -ExpandProperty Url` from the initial cmdlet so that you can access more data.

Comment: When I delete Select -ExpandProperty Url it does not change output at all. In case of bare shellpoint script for changing LockState what is better? With or without parameter?

Comment: Also can't see to make it work... `Connect-SPOService -Url https://xxx-admin.sharepoint.com
$allSites = Get-SPOSite -IncludePersonalSite $true -Limit all -Filter "Url -like '-my.sharepoint.com/personal/'" | Select -ExpandProperty Url
foreach ($site in $allSites) {
  Where-object -Identity $site -LockState NoAccess
}`

Comment: This doesn't work too: `$allSites = Get-SPOSite -IncludePersonalSite $true -Limit all -Filter "Url -like '-my.sharepoint.com/personal/'"
foreach ($site in $allSites) {
$site where -LockState NoAccess
}`

Comment: Based on what you pasted, you might definitely benefit from reading more about `Where-Object`. If you're stuck with any specific problem, you're more than welcome to open a new question. At that point I'd have to write whole script for you, which is not how [so] works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with to get all sites that are locked.  It includes all information fields.  Change the export path to a destination that's appropriate for you:

```
Get-sposite -includepersonalsite $true -Limit ALL -Filter "LockState -like 'NoAccess'" |Export-csv -Path 'C:\PowerShell\OneDriveSitesLocked.csv' -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation
```